# Access-Control-Allow-Origin server mods are not working

Tags: wordpress, nginx, cors, wordpress-rest-api

I am having a terrible time trying to get my server to accept requests from another server (local, but given a domain name in my hosts file) without triggering the dreaded

`XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://dev.mydomain.org/api/user?uid=1. Origin http://home.domain.org is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.`

my dev server (internet) is running nginx, my home server(local) is running apache.

I have tried several solutions found on the internet, to no avail. I have tried modifying the headers in the nginx configs to allow my home.mydomain.org server, I have also added htaccess rules locally to allow all origins (*).

My nginx server block has these lines currently:

```
   add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin http://home.mydomain.org; 
   add_header Access-Control-Allow-Headers Authorization;
```

Adding just the first one did change my response slightly (from simple `Origin not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin` to `Request header field Authorization is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers.`) but adding the second line just reverted the error to the original one and I am still blocked.

At this point, I am not sure what else to try.

UPDATES:

1. Launching Chrome with flag --disable-web-security allows me to test, and my site and code is working fine in Chrome.
2. However, this revealed another strange problem, which is that if I try adding the add_header lines to a location directive, both my no-web-security Chrome and my unmodified Safari fail to load info from my api. So now I am not sure if my add_header directives in the server block are working correctly at all.

If it helps any, here is my client code (including things I have tried/commented out):

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var self = this;
xhr.open('GET', apiURL + self.currentIssue);
xhr.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','http://home.mydomain.org');
//xhr.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');
xhr.withCredentials = true;
//xhr.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Request-Method','*');
xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization','Bearer longstringoflettersandnumbers');
xhr.onload = function () {
        self.posts = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        };
xhr.send();
```

ANOTHER UPDATE AFTER TRYING SUGGESTION BELOW:
After a bunch of trial and error on both client and server, I still am stuck. Here is my latest response from the server using curl (although I have toggled on and off various options client and server for things like Credentials and changing origin to exactly mine or * to no avail):

`HTTP/1.1 204 No Content
Server: nginx
Date: Sun, 06 Aug 2017 10:11:57 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://home.mydomain.org
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization,DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Content-Range,Range
Access-Control-Max-Age: 1728000
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 0`

and here are my console errors (Safari):

```
[Error] Origin http://home.mydomain.org is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
[Error] Failed to load resource: Origin http://home.mydomain.org is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. (actions, line 0)
[Error] XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://dev.mydomain.org/api/user?uid=1 due to access control checks.
```

And here is my console error for Firefox:

`Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://dev.mydomain.org/api/user?uid=1. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).`

Also in Firefox, here are the results from the network panel for OPTIONS and GET:

```
Request URL: https://dev.mydomain.org/api/user?uid=1
Request method: OPTIONS
Status code: 204 No Content
Version: HTTP/2.0

Response headers (511 B)    
Server  "nginx"
Date    "Sun, 06 Aug 2017 10:44:22 GMT"
Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://home.mydomain.org"
access-control-allow-credentials    "true"
Access-Control-Allow-Methods    "GET, POST, OPTIONS"
Access-Control-Allow-Headers    "Authorization,DNT,X-CustomHea…ent-Type,Content-Range,Range"
Access-Control-Max-Age  "1728000"
Content-Type    "text/plain; charset=utf-8"
Content-Length  "0"
X-Firefox-Spdy  "h2"
Request headers (501 B) 
Host    "dev.mydomain.org"
User-Agent  "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel… Gecko/20100101 Firefox/54.0"
Accept  "text/html,application/xhtml+x…lication/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8"
Accept-Language "en-US,en;q=0.5"
Accept-Encoding "gzip, deflate, br"
Access-Control-Request-Method   "GET"
Access-Control-Request-Headers  "authorization"
Origin  "http://home.mydomain.org"
Connection  "keep-alive"
Cache-Control   "max-age=0"


Request URL: https://dev.mydomain.org/api/user?uid=1
Request method: GET
Status code: 404 Not Found
Version: HTTP/2.0

Response headers (170 B)    
Server  "nginx"
Date    "Sun, 06 Aug 2017 10:44:22 GMT"
Content-Type    "text/html"
Vary    "Accept-Encoding"
Content-Encoding    "gzip"
X-Firefox-Spdy  "h2"
Request headers (723 B) 
Host    "dev.mydomain.org"
User-Agent  "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel… Gecko/20100101 Firefox/54.0"
Accept  "*/*"
Accept-Language "en-US,en;q=0.5"
Accept-Encoding "gzip, deflate, br"
Referer "http://home.mydomain.org/"
Authorization   "Bearer eyJ0eXAG…BRHmX9VmtYHQOvH7k-Y32wwyeCdk"
Origin  "http://home.mydomain.org"
Connection  "keep-alive"
Cache-Control "max-age=0"
```

UPDATE WITH PARTIAL SUCESS:

I think I found the problem (partially): changing my location directive in nginx from `location /api` to `location = /api/*` gets it working! But only for Safari and Chrome, FF is now not even trying the GET request, there is NO entry for it in network panel.

UPDATE WITH CRYING AND GNASHING OF TEETH AND PULLING OF HAIR
Safari and Chrome intermittently fail with original error about Origin not allowed, even though they were working fine and no changes have been made to server config. I will be drinking heavily tonight...

Comment: Your nginx config looks correct. Please update your question to include the exact error message you’re seeing in your browser devtools console after adding the `add_header Access-Control-Allow-Headers Authorization` line.

Comment: Like I said above, it just reverts to the original `Origin not allowed` message.

Comment: https://enable-cors.org/server_nginx.html shows what a complete CORS config setup for nginx should look like. You probably want to try following that as closely as possible. There’s unfortunately not enough detail in your question to be able to know, but it seems like what might be happening is some problem in the response coming back for the OPTIONS request the browser will make due to the presence of the Authorization header in your request. (Assuming there is an Authorization header in the request—can’t be certain because your question as-is give no details about the request…)

Comment: Thanks, but I tried it (even adding Authorization to the Headers  lists) and have the exact same result as above, alas.

Comment: You should remove the `xhr.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','http://home.mydomain.org')`. Access-Control-Allow-Origin is strictly a response header for servers to send. The only effect sending it from the client side as request header will cause is to make a CORS preflight fail. Same thing or the commented-out `//xhr.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true')`. Access-Control-Allow-Credentials is strictly response header, so you definitely don’t want to uncomment.

Comment: General point: As far as the CORS protocol goes, there are no Access-Control-* headers than you can manually set on the client side for requests. All Access-Control-Allow-* headers are strictly response headers. There are three Access-Control-* that can be sent automatically by the browser itself from the client side, but those also you never want to set manually in your own code. To understand how the CORS protocol works, it helps to read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS carefully and thoroughly

Comment: The curl output looks fine and if that’s what your browser is also receiving, should result a successful preflight—as long as you’ve also dropped the `xhr.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','http://home.mydomain.org')` from the request.

Comment: I did, but I am still getting the same errors (which I just added above)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow, was that ever convoluted. Posting answer here in case some other WP user finds their way here. I kept getting inconsistent results (sometimes working, sometimes not mysteriously) and finally tracked down my problem to headers being set in the PHP code on the server, independently of the nginx settings and sometimes contradicting them (although never in a predictable way that I could see). So the things I needed to resolve were:

- Removed all my cors declarations in my nginx configs
- I also have code on my server that validates a token in the auth header, and it was failing on OPTIONS preflight (which it should never check) so I had to add an if statement before to have it ignore an OPTIONS call (`!$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === "OPTIONS"`)
- Since I had cloned this site from another of mine using UpdraftPlus plugin, I had to go in to delete my migrate keys since their existence prevented api calls from working too. Once they were deleted my calls started working again.
- Removed and re-added the built in WP filter `rest_pre_serve_request`

My filter code is here:

```
add_action('rest_api_init', function() {
/* unhook default function */
remove_filter('rest_pre_serve_request', 'rest_send_cors_headers');   
/* then add your own filter */
add_filter('rest_pre_serve_request', function( $value ) {
$origin = get_http_origin();
$my_sites = array( $origin ); // add array of accepted sites if you prefer
if ( in_array( $origin, $my_sites ) ) {
header( 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: ' . esc_url_raw( $origin ) );
} else {
header( 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: ' . esc_url_raw( site_url() ) );
}
header( 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods: OPTIONS, GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE' );
header( 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true' );
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization,DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Origin,Content-Type,X-Auth-Token,Content-Range,Range');
header('Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Authorization,DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Origin,Content-Type,X-Auth-Token,Content-Range,Range');
header( 'Vary: Origin' );
return $value;
});
}, 15);
```

Now finally, everything works everywhere (in every browser and in curl too)!